# Are PHP global constants a good modern development practice?

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection, tdd

I'm working on a new project with a sizeable PHP codebase. The application uses quite a few PHP constants ( `define('FOO', 'bar')` ), particularly for things like database connection parameters. These constants are all defined in a single configuration file that is `require_once()`'d directly by basically every class in the application.

A few years ago this would have made perfect sense, but since then I've gotten the Unit Testing bug and this tight coupling between classes is really bothering me. These constants smell like global variables, and they're referenced directly throughout the application code.

Is this still a good idea? Would it be reasonable to copy these values into an object and use this object (i.e. a Bean - there, I said it) to convey them via dependency injection to the the classes that interact with the database? Am I defeating any of the benefits of PHP constants (say speed or something) by doing this?

Another approach I'm considering would be be to create a separate configuration PHP script for testing. I'll still need to figure a way to get the classes under test to use the sandbox configuration script instead of the global configuration script. This still feels brittle, but it might require less outright modification to the entire application.

Comment: `#define CONSTANTS 'are fine'`?

Comment: @Marc B: sooo much love!

Comment: These constants are/were (super) global variables that can be set only once. That's why they have been used for configuration - not for testing reasons but (as no tests were done) to ensure they are not changed by the rest of the hot cocked and cheese-backed spaghetti code - just to ensure no part of the code does ... ;) - so choose the right tool for the job. It's an art to get legacy code under test step by step. Removing constants can be part of that.

Comment: This type of question, where the answers are opinions or discussions, is not fitting for Stack Overflow. As per the [faq], **You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.** The close reason for "not constructive" lists reasons such as **this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion**. As such, I'm closing it as "not constructive".

Comment: @Artefacto Just Read the answers. "In my opinion", "I agree", "I disagree", "It is important to discuss".

Comment: I respectfully disagree, @Lasse. I found the answers extremely useful. I can find facts by just reading the documentation - I needed experienced opinions and rationales to help clarify my understanding of how this works in practice.

Comment: I changed the wording of the question slightly to make it a little more focused on the real issue.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, while i agree that the answers are subjective, I believe that it **is** constructive. A generalized version of this question could easily be asked on Programmers.SE, but given the number of votes and *quality* of the activity on this question there is no reason to close it. Closing as "not constructive" is better used for argumentative questions.

Comment: Ok, I finalized the 3 votes to reopen it. I'm not saying that closing it is/was wrong, but the community has spoken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, constants should be used only in two circumstances:

- Actual constant values (i.e. things that will never change, `SECONDS_PER_HOUR`).
- OS-dependent values, as long as the constant can be used transparently by the application, in every situation possible.

Even then, I'd reconsider whether class constants would be more appropriate so as not to pollute the constants space.

In your situation, I'd say constants are not a good solution because you will want to provide alternative values depending on where they're used.

Comment: An example could be the file extension for php files `define('EXT', '.php')` which will not change page to page and is global for the project.

Comment: This really helped me get at the root of issue. I think it's not that constants in question are constants, it's that they're global that really causes the problems.

Comment: Well... if you don't pollute the constants space, you have a space not used. You don't save it for anything: you're only losing a language feature (and I respect the choice NOT to use define).

Answer (score 5):

> These constants smell like global variables, and they're referenced directly […]. Would it be reasonable to copy these values into an object and […] convey them via dependency injection?

Absolutely! I would go even further and say even class constants should be avoided. Because they are public, they expose internals and they are API, so you cannot change them easily without risking breaking existing applications due to the tight coupling. A configuration object makes much more sense (just dont make it a Singleton).

Also see:

- [Brittle Global State & Singletons](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/) from
- http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

Comment: Friendly suggestion to better explain your first sentence. The title and wording of the question itself somewhat contradict each other. The title asks 'are constants good?', but the body reads more like 'are constants bad?'. It's difficult to tell which side you're taking.

Comment: @Mike sorry if it wasn't clear: "absolutely" refers to the OP's concern that constants are global state and to the idea to use a Config Object instead.

Answer (score 4):

To answer this question it is important to discuss the style of code being written.

PHP 5 includes a number of useful OOP features, one of which is class constants. If you're using an object oriented approach, rather than polluting the global namespace, or worry about overriding common constants, you should use class constants.

`FOO_BAR` could be `FOO::BAR` in the end, it comes down to the scope of where you want the constant defined.

If you're writing a more procedural style program, or mixing procedural with some classes, global constants aren't an issue. If the code you're working on is becoming unmanageable due to the constants you're using, try changing things around. Otherwise, don't worry about it.

Additionally, class constants wont allow you to use function return values, global constants *will*. This is great when you have a value that wont ever be changed throughout the scope of the program, but needs to be generated.

Answer (score 2):

using constants for database connection information is perfectly fine. This prevents hard-coding it within the object itself and since its read-only you can't overwrite the values.

I'm not fond of hard-coding my settings in an object, as things can change, but if you wanted to do that, that would work just as well.

Comment: It becomes a major problem when unit testing. Better to use dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

If You have PHP 5.3 or newer, You may use `namespace`.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

It works with `const variable = 'something';`
Unfortunately, it doesn't wokrk with `define('variable','something');`

Globals in namespace are encapsulated. In some situations it is better than having an object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree constants, nor the hardcode :-)

I prefer, performance aside, Zend_Config_Ini from ZendFramework.

You can overload sections, maintain the values read-only in memory, and others:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html